# How to make that Pyqt5 LineEdit accepts only numbers

Tags: python, pyqt

Currently, I am working on a program with python and PYQT5 where user inputs have to be only numbers. The problem is that I have no idea how to do it. For example when I get this variable

```py
VAR_1=float(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
```

I need that the text entered is only a number. i mean when the user is trying to write a letter o symbol nothing happens.

Comment: Qt provides [QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html), which already does what you need for integers, while if you need floats there is [QDoubleSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html). It's possible to implement QLineEdit in order to do the same, but that's usually for very rare and very specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use/Try **setValidator** or **setInputMask**  methods

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class ButtonName(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Example - Validator")
        self.setGeometry(800, 200, 200, 200)
        self.UI()
        self.layouts()
        self.show()

    def UI(self):
        self.lbl_integer = QLabel("Integer Validator")
        self.textbox_integervalidator = QLineEdit()
        self.textbox_integervalidator.setPlaceholderText("upto 3 digit value only accept")
        self.textbox_integervalidator.setValidator(QIntValidator(1, 999, self))

        self.lbl_double = QLabel("Double Validator")
        self.textbox_doublevalidator = QLineEdit()
        self.textbox_doublevalidator.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0.99, 99.99, 2))

        self.lbl_regexp = QLabel("RexExp Validator")
        self.textbox_regexpvalidator = QLineEdit()
        reg_ex_1 = QRegExp("[0-9]+.?[0-9]{,2}") # double
        # reg_ex_2 = QRegExp("[0-9]{1,5}")  # minimum 1 integer number to maxiumu 5 integer number
        # reg_ex_3 = QRegExp("-?\\d{1,3}")  # accept negative number also
        # reg_ex_4 = QRegExp("")
        self.textbox_regexpvalidator.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(reg_ex_1))

    def layouts(self):
        mainlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainlayout.addWidget(self.lbl_integer)
        mainlayout.addWidget(self.textbox_integervalidator)
        mainlayout.addWidget(self.lbl_double)
        mainlayout.addWidget(self.textbox_doublevalidator)
        mainlayout.addWidget(self.lbl_regexp)
        mainlayout.addWidget(self.textbox_regexpvalidator)
        self.setLayout(mainlayout)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = ButtonName()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You mentioned using `setInputMask`, would you care to explain that too?

Comment: I'd suggest also creating subclass with `value`, `setValue` methods and `valueChanged` signal.

Comment: for phone number format -> self.textbox_inputmask_1.setInputMask("+99-99999 99999;_") ,
 for date  format->self.textbox_inputmask_2.setInputMask("99/99/9999;_")  . for alpha numeric format -> self.textbox_inputmask_3.setInputMask(">99AAAAA9999A9A9; ") @ musicamante

Answer (score 2):

try make a mask for your line edit:

```py
self.lineEdit.setInputMask("00")
```

When you put "0" in Mask, the code will understand that it can only be numbers. The amount of zero placed will be the amount of houses that the lineedit will accept. In this case how and "00" the lineEdit accepted two houses (the ten's houses)

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

**self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.accept_only_numbers)**

```
def accept_only_numbers(self): 
    VAR_1=float(self.ui.lineEdit.text()) 
    if  VAR_1.isnumeric() == True:
        print("ok is number") 
    else:
        VAR_1.clear()
```